# Why `func || (..args) => {...}` does not compile?

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

The following snippet does not compile:

```
const a = a || (...args) => {
  console.log(args);
}
```

With the following error:

```
repl: Unexpected token (1:16)
> 1 | const a = a || (...args) => {
    |                 ^
  2 |   console.log(args);
  3 | }
```

With the following workaround, it works:

```
const a = a ? a : (...args) => {
  console.log(args);
}
```

---

Besides the original problem, which has been resolved by @loganfsmyth . Next question is, why the following code works?

```
const a = a || () => {}
```

Comment: Why are you using `a` like that? You are declaring `a` with `const a`, so it will never have a value that you'll need to check at that line. Is this just example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate issues in this code. The specific answer to your questions is that you need parens, e.g.

```
const a = a || ((...args) => {
  console.log(args);
});
```

however that will also not work because you are also reading `a` before it has been initialized, which will trigger a temporal-dead-zone error to be thrown. It's not clear why you'd use `a` like that in this code though.

Comment: Well, the second issue is OK, that is only for my code snippet. Your suggestion resolve my problem. Thanks very much! But why this works? `const a = a || () => {}`

Comment: That I don't know off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: It seems like `x = a || (…) => …` does not work to avoid the ambiguity in `x = (…) => … || a;` (`ArrowFunction` is an `AssignmentExpression`, but not an `OrExpression`). I neither can't tell why `a || () => {}` works though.